# Angular ng-show Still Shows <div> Element When Empty

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

How can I hide/remove the containing `<div>` element when the value is empty:

```
<div class="small" ng-show="ID !== ''">{{ info.ID }} | </div>
```

Renders:

```
<div class="small">|</div>
```

Can I remove the `<div>` completely if empty? I've tried:

```
<div class="small" ng-show="!ID">{{ info.ID }}</div >
```

Comment: This can't be both angular-js and angular. Which one is it?

Comment: `ng-show="info.ID"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking value of `ID` property which is not the `ID` within `info` object so use `info.ID` within the `ng-show`.

```
<div class="small" ng-show="info.ID">{{ info.ID }} | </div>
<!-- -----------------------^^^^^^^----------------------->
```

---

If you don't want to render the element itself then use [`ng-if` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) since [`ng-show` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) simply hide using some CSS.

```
<div class="small" ng-if="info.ID">{{ info.ID }} | </div>
<!-- ---------------------^^^^^^^----------------------->
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide the element then use:

```
<div class="small" [hidden]="info?.ID">{{ info?.ID }}</div>
```

If you alse want to avoid rendering it (which is better in most cases) then use:

```
<div class="small" *ngIf="info?.ID">{{ info?.ID }}</div>
```

Use the Elvis operator otherwise you may get this mistake:

> Can't get ID of null